# flatten a 2d matrix of unsigned integers into a double in C++

Tags: c++

I have a 2D matrix which has 28 values: `unsigned int CorrelatedF_int[j][k];`  with j= 4 and k=7.
I want to convert this matrix into a double : `double CorrelatedF_int[27];`. This double should contain all the 28 values multiplied by 1000 each. I searched on this site, but I didn't find any answers that could help me solve the problem. So how can I do this conversion? as I am a beginner in C++, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: offtopic: you are using C extension (variadic length array) which is not allowed in standard C++.

Answer (score 2):

Assumed rowed based order in flattened array:

```
constexpr int M = 4;
constexpr int N = 7;
unsigned int ui_arr[M][N];
double d_arr[M * N] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < M * N; ++i)
    d_arr[i] = 1000 * ui_arr[i / N][i % N];
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how many rows and columns,so I will use n and m.
You can do something like this

```
double arr[28];
int k=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
             arr[k]=(double)matrix[i][j]*1000;
                k++;
}
```

Where arr is array of double values.

Answer (score 1):

C++20 ranges style:

```cpp
template<size_t N, size_t M>
std::array<double, N*M> join_to_double_array(const std::array<std::array<int, N>, M>& a)
{
    std::array<double, N*M> result;

    using std::ranges::views::join;
    std::ranges::copy(a | join, result.begin());

    return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9a7KTK